# mongoimport loading only 1000 rows on sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongoimport

I have a mongo sharding setup configuration like
6 config server
3 shard server (with replica)
6 router

```
for example:

**s1->s2  (one shard with replicat (primary:s1,secondry:s2))
s3->s4  (2nd shard with replics (primary s3, secondry s4))
s5->s6  (third shard with replics (primary s5, secondry s6))
config, router is on all server i.e s1 to s6**
```

I am not able to import data to one of the empty sharded collection ,      data is in csv format.

I m running mongoimport in background and the nohup out shows like this

```
**2017-01-10T17:13:18.444+0530        [........................]   dbname.collectionname        364.0 KB/46.1 MB (0.8%)**


mongoimport is stuck , how to fix this.
```

I first tried to run mongoimport on s2 but not succeeded then try to run mongoimport on s1 no success

follwing are the errors servers from routerlog , configuration log

```
**HostnameCanonicalizationWorker
[rsBackgroundSync] we are too stale to use **** as a 
sync source
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] could not find member to sync from
REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] The liveness timeout does not match    callback handle, so not resetting it.
REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] too stale to catch up -- entering maintenance mode**
```